# In this sentence what "put up" means and is there a way to learn phrasal verbs quickly?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrasal-verbs

> Men and women were painting the walls while others were putting up
> partitions.

I looked at the dictionary but none of the definitions appeared to be matching with the meaning used here. In this sentence, what's the meaning of put up?

If it is used to say build, I'm sorry for asking a question that is easy to find its solution.

Comment: *up* means *upright position*, *put* means *place*. Together, *place in an upright (vertical) position*.

Comment: "Is there a way to learn phrasal verbs quickly" - I don't think there is any way other than by seeing them used and learning what they mean.  Consider **throw out, throw up, throw down, throw away, throw over**, etc.  There may not be any obvious connection between the main verb and the meaning of the phrasal verb.  Or between the preposition and the phrasal verb: **throw up** doesn't mean the same thing as **put up**...except that sometimes it does, depending on the context!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**put up**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_up), verb
> 10. (*transitive*) To build a structure.

Comment: Grammatically, "put up" is not a verb but a verb + a preposition. At word level they don't form a grammatical unit.

Comment: @BillJ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phrasal_verbs

Comment: It's complete nonsense. Wiki is a joke in this respect!

Comment: @BillJ is the OED also a joke? https://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/glossary/#phrase

Comment: There is an unwritten rule that dictionaries are fine for meanings, but not for grammar. This is very simple grammar that you should try to grasp. Consider the point I made in my earlier comment.